# Delete parent object when child object is deleted in Django

Tags: django, django-models

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class B(modes.Model):
    type_b = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

In a one-to-many relationship in Django, how do I delete the "one" object (model 'A') when I delete one of the related "many" objects (model 'B')? I'm deleting the model 'B' object through the Django admin bulk delete option.

Comment: But I think you have to add this "on_delete=models.CASCADE"  to ForeignKey field and then you can remove A(models) which will automatically remove B(models).

Answer (score 3):

You should use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-delete).

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=B)
def delete_a(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     # instance.type_b is the object which you want to delete
```

Comment: When I try to delete using `instance.type_b.delete()` I'm getting `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'` error

Comment: @albinantony Do this way A.objects.filter(pk=instance.type_b.pk).delete()

Comment: What if the user has permissions only on the child model and not on the parent model? Would the `post_delete` signal work to delete both? @DavitTovmasyan

Comment: @filtfilt You will get an error, you should add a check for it.

Answer (score 2):

A best way to do it, just add `[on_delete=models.CASCADE][1]`

:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class B(modes.Model):
    type_b = models.ForeignKey(A,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: I have tried `models.CASCADE` but it is not working as expected.

Comment: As Davit Tovmasyan said, try to use SIGNAL post_delete

Answer (score 0):

You can use post_delete signal to delete the parent as suggested by Davit Tovmasyan.

BUT because of the cascading nature as the parent A object is deleted, it will also delete all the connected B objects which will inturn emit `post_delete` signal on B model. So on the second emit of `post_delete` the signal handler tries to delete an already deleted item which causes `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'`. You can use exception handler or just use the if condition to handle this.

```
def delete_parent(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.type_b:
        instance.type_b.delete()

post_delete.connect(delete_parent, sender=B)
```